# Difficulty to parameterize scale with 2 screens

Tags: display-resolution

I have a Dell Inspiron 7000 14" FHD with resolution of 1920x1080. All things show so small. For example, Google font show like size 5, the size of font existent on the instructions on a medicine, impossible for me that don't have perfect vision. So I change the scale of the system and size of fonts to adapt. But when I connect my external monitor(Dell U2312HM 23"), all things show so big on the monitor. I have tried to fix this with xrandr, unfortunately no success.

Info:

```
   :~$  xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1081, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I found a person with a similar situation, that resolve wih this command:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --panning 3840x1080+3200+0 --scale 2x2 --left-of eDP1
```

I try this, but it didn't work for me.

Anyone already got over it, this "inconvenience"? I believe there is a simple solution, but unfortunately, the attempts I have made, have not resolved the issue.

Comment: Provide information on the desktop you use, because the answer may depend on this. Are you using a standard current Ubuntu version with the Gnome desktop, or another Ubuntu flavor.

Comment: Thanks to answer. This situation was repeated in different distros, at first I imagined that it was a mistake of my configuration. But it happened with Ubuntu 18.10 (standart), ElementaryOS 5 and Fedora 29. After that I started to get help online, and I started to understand the problem a little better.

Comment: Add this information to your question. If you solve the issue, do not hesitate to answer yourself and accept the anser.

Comment: So far I have not been able to solve this difference of scale with two monitors. When I learn how to do it, I share.